# Git Branch (off branch) failing

Tags: git

I've checked out a repo with many remote branches. Locally I've got 'master' and 'staging' checked out. I want to make a new branch 'mobile-code' which is based on 'staging', so I'm using:

```
git checkout -b mobile-code staging
```

but I get:

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

I'm on OSx Yosemite. Other git commands work, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong there...

Any help greatly appreciated. :)

PS When I come to push, do I need to push both 'staging' and 'mobile-code'? And will it auto-create the new branch on the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be on the branch you're basing your new branch off of before creating it.

```
git checkout staging
git checkout -b mobile-code
```

When you want to push your branch, just push that particular branch.

```
git push -u origin mobile-code
```

Unless you make changes to your `staging` branch, you don't need to push it.

Comment: Thanks @Makato. I found the docs at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout really confusing... :/